# "label" for process to be able to kill it by "label"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to run more player programs at once (in linux), but I want to kill it by subprocess separately. So I am thinking about something like adding "label" for each player process when I start it, e.g. player "1", player "2", player "3", player "3", player "3" and then I would like to call subprocess to kill all instances of player "3".

How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean *more player programs at once*?

Comment: that I execute more instances of player via subprocess.popen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your labels are unique you can simply save the `popen` instances in a dictionary with the label as the key.

```
import subprocess
process_dict = {}

def startNewProcess(command, label):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    process_dict[label] = p

def killProcess(label):
    if label in m_process_dict:
        p = process_dict.pop(label)
        p.terminate()
```

If the process labels will not be unique, or if you want to have multiple labels per process, it may be better to use a list and save both the process and your labels.

```
import subprocess
process_list = {}

def startNewProcess(command, labels):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    process_list.append({'process':p, 'labels':labels})

def killProcess(label):
    for ii, entry in enumerate(process_list):
        if label in entry['labels']:
             entry['process'].terminate()
             process_list.remove(ii)
```